# How to delete 'uid=,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local' in opends/ldap?

Tags: ldap, opends

by accident wrong entry was added to ldap:

```
uid=,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local
```

Which screwed up our ou=people..
Now we can't even delete that entry:

```
ldapdelete -h localhost -p 1389 -D cn=admin -w password -vvv "ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local"
```

Error we're getting is:

```
DELETE operation failed
Result Code:  34 (Invalid DN Syntax)
Additional Information:  The provided value "uid=,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local" could not be parsed as a valid distinguished name because an attribute value started with a character at position 5 that needs to be escaped
```

I tried escaping character, special characters but still no dice.

How can we remove 'ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local'??

Is that even possible or we have to reinstall opends/ldap?

Thanks

Comment: You may have to dump to LDIF, edit out the entry, and restore.

Comment: I would do the same thing @EJP suggested. It is already rather surprising that you was able to create this entry because LDAP operations should be syntaxically checked before applying modifications. Only way to bypass these controls is on a dump restore

Comment: I created ldif file with export-ldif but entry "uid=,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=local" does NOT exist in there.

Comment: I tried removing backend userRoot but openDS complaints that I can't connect to administration port but that port is configured and listening. Any advice appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is your "uid" value in the `dn`? Can you send a `dn` with a key missing?